# Cannot index URL with parameter, appended to prevent redirect on first access. "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical" message

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, canonical-url

I have a language learning website.

The main app page (https://www.example.com/vocab/learn) is accessed via https://www.example.com/vocab/app, where the user can either login, register, or preview as guest.

I am trying to get the main app page indexed on Google. However, on the first run, the website is designed to redirect to https://www.example.com/vocab/first-run, where the user goes through a tutorial.

Hence, I coded the page such that, if there is a parameter `nfr=0` in the link, it will not redirect.
https://www.example.com/vocab/learn?nfr=0

Now, here's my problem. Unfortunately, initially there was a bug in the code and it redirected to the login page. When Google crawled that link, it excluded that link from indexing, giving the error,

> Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical

I have since fixed the bug and requested indexing twice, yet it does not change status. It still shows that error and in the details page, it shows that the login page is the canonical detected page and not vocab/learn.

I request help in getting Google to recognise the right canonical page and include it in indexing.

Comment: How long has it been since you requested reindexing?  It can take a few weeks, especially for new sits.

Comment: @Trebor my website has been around for quite a while. I requested indexing via the Inspect URL tool, which makes Google crawl that specific link on priority. On both occassions it got crawled within an hour and it does show the crawl date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a url with a parameter to Google, Google Bot will try to access to the same Url without any parameter. So the best practice is toyour url /learn and to have a separate link to the url first run.

Comment: The /vocab/learn page and /vocab/first-run page are different. It's just that, on the first run, instead of opening /vocab/learn, it redirects to /vocab/first-run to make the user go through the tutorial first

Comment: Remember Google will always be in the first Run behavior because it could not create an account or have cookies. So if you want to help the bot indexing both page, you need to build your internal linking in a google way with its constraint.